# Strategy for Rails app to hook into an engine's workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

I've created an engine with a defined workflow. Messages come in, are handled in some way, and are sent out. Now I want to let the application using this engine hook into the flow and modify the handling of the message.

I've thought of adding an initializer in the app and just monkeypatch the engine's message handling class, but it makes me feel a little dirty.

I'm sure there is a more sensible way of doing stuff like this. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: In my humble opinion, monkey patching the engine's class IS the way to go. Even when you're working with gems instead of engines, you have to monkey patch them to modify their behaviour, e.g. Devise.

Comment: There are several ways. Hard to judge without specific code example.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question that expects a "good" answer, but I post as answer for proper code formatting.

This sounds a lot like a javascript callback scheme. That something we usually does in ruby, with blocks.

Monkey patching sounds certainly not sexy as an expected api, and it always looks hackish from user perspective. I would probably go like using a class method taking a block, like :

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyEngineConcern

  on_engine_stuff do |message|
    create!( name: 'hello', message: message )
  end
end
```

Your engine class can then use it :

```
module MyEngineConcern
  def self.included( base )
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def on_engine_stuff( &callback )
      MyEngine::Callbacks.add callback
    end
  end
end

module MyEngine
  class Callbacks
    class << self
      @_callbacks = []

      def add( callback )
        @_callbacks << callback
      end

      def process( message )
        @_callbacks.each do |callback|
          message = callback.call( message )
        end

        message
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note this implies your engine is accessed by models, we would probably need a bit more information about it to suggest a proper design.

Comment: I like the this idea, although it might not be feasible for my case. I'm not going to access the engine from my apps models, actually the functionality in the app would only ever be triggered by the engine's model. Guess I'd need to somehow add the callbacks using an initializer, but really unsure how I would be able to persist it across requests. Any ideas?